# Creating hive table: no files matching path file... but the file exist in the path

Tags: hadoop, hive

Im trying to create a hive orc table using a file stored in hdfs.

I have a table "partsupp.tbl" file where each line have the below format:

```
 1|25002|8076|993.49|ven ideas. quickly even packages print. pending multipliers must have to are fluff|
```

I create a hive table like this:

```
create table if not exists partsupp (PS_PARTKEY BIGINT,
 PS_SUPPKEY BIGINT,
 PS_AVAILQTY INT,
 PS_SUPPLYCOST DOUBLE,
 PS_COMMENT STRING)
STORED AS ORC TBLPROPERTIES ("orc.compress"="SNAPPY")
;
```

Now Im trying to load the data in the .tbl file in the table like this:

```
LOAD DATA  LOCAL INPATH '/tables/partsupp/partsupp.tbl' INTO TABLE partsupp
```

But Im getting this issue:

```
No files matching path file:/tables/partsupp/partsupp.tbl
```

But the files exists in the hdfs...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`LOCAL` signifies that file is present on the local file system.  If 'LOCAL' is omitted then it looks for the file in HDFS.

So in this case, use following query:

```
LOAD DATA  INPATH '/tables/partsupp/partsupp.tbl' INTO TABLE partsupp
```

Comment: Thanks its working with your solution. But now im having an error with your code, when I select * from partsupp I get this: Failed: Execution error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.sql.exec.mr.MapRedTask